# Update values in nested object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have this object:

```
{
   b954WYBCC4YbsMM36trawb00xZ32: { activity1: "pending", activity2: "pending" },
​   pby0CAqQ1hTlagIqBTQf6l2Ti9L2: { activity1: "pending", activity2: "pending" }
}
```

where the first keys are IDs from a database. I want to be able to change the values of `activity1` and `activity2` based on an array:

```
// 'data' is the object mentioned above.
const usersHaveSpecialContentAssigned = [true, false];

Object.values(data).forEach((item, index) => {
    const arrayActivityProgress = Object.values(item as string[]);
    if (usersHaveSpecialContentAssigned[index] === false) {
        arrayActivityProgress.forEach((progress) => {
            progress = 'unassigned';
            console.log(progress);
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, my goal is to change the values of `activity1` and `activity2` if the corresponding value in `usersHaveSpecialContentAssigned` is `false`.

The end result based on the example above should look like this:

```
{
   b954WYBCC4YbsMM36trawb00xZ32: { activity1: "pending", activity2: "pending" },
​   pby0CAqQ1hTlagIqBTQf6l2Ti9L2: { activity1: "unassigned", activity2: "unassigned" }
}
```

How can I achieve this? My current approach doesn't update the values.

Comment: primitive values aren't referenced values, so changing one variable holding a primitive value has no effect on another variable assigned the same value. If you want to mutate the objects in `data` you need to do so explicitly ie. `item.activity1 = 'unassigned'`

Comment: Firstly you are better off passing in true or false into your function rather than an index. As in any language, false = 0 and true = 1, whereas your index is the opposite, but it is just easier to pass true or false.

Comment: Hint: if I do `const o = [1]; let [a] = o; a = 3; console.log(o[0]);` it logs 1 not 3. Assigning to a function parameter in the `forEach` callback doesn't change the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know what the ids are going to be, I would write it this way.

```
var initialData = {
   b954WYBCC4YbsMM36trawb00xZ32: { activity1: "pending", activity2: "pending" },
​   pby0CAqQ1hTlagIqBTQf6l2Ti9L2: { activity1: "pending", activity2: "pending" }
};
var permissionsPerUserDataIn = {"b954WYBCC4YbsMM36trawb00xZ32": true, "pby0CAqQ1hTlagIqBTQf6l2Ti9L2": false, "id3": false};
```

and write your function like this:

```
function fixData(permissionsPerUser) {

    for (var [id, values] of Object.entries(initialData)) {
       if (permissionsPerUser.hasOwnProperty(id) && !permissionsPerUser[id]) {  
           values.activity1 = 'unassigned';
           values.activity2 = 'unassigned';
           console.log(`${id}: `, values);
       }
    }
}

fixData(permissionsPerUserDataIn);
```

Doing it this way will give you more granular control over what permissions will get updated and you will not have to worry if a value in the array gets out of sync for whatever reason.

Comment: Your answer is the closest to the solution I came up with, and in fact, I used your answer as a general baseline. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
Object.values(data).forEach((item, index) => {
    if (!usersHaveSpecialContentAssigned[index])
        item.activity1 = item.activity2 = "unassigned";
```

You of course need to watch for the index not to be out of range.